# Can't getItem - not getting back any results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to make a very simple getitem request to DynamoDb from lambda, but I'm not getting back any results.

Yes, I checked the permissions and they made sure that they are granted for lambda execution and dynamodb getitem functions for the appropriate table and that they are correctly attached to the lambda function.

Yes, there is definitely an entry in that table with name: "Bobas".

Here is what I'm getting from console.logs :

```
START RequestId: 1db3eebb-8edb-4bfa-987d-4afc9831c7b6 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 1db3eebb-8edb-4bfa-987d-4afc9831c7b6
REPORT RequestId: 1db3eebb-8edb-4bfa-987d-4afc9831c7b6  Duration: 680.59 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 91 MB  Init Duration: 366.03 ms
```

Code follows:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'ca-central-1'});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let resp;
    // TODO implement
    const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});

    const params = {
        TableName: 'trivia-users',
        Key: {
            name: {
                S: 'Bobas'
            }
        }
    }

    ddb.getItem(params, (err, data) => {
        let resp = data;
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return resp;

};
```

Comment: Not sure it will make a difference, but can you try adding using "name", with quotes, instead of just name without quotes?

Comment: I tried all the variations of quotes/no-quotes. Some examples have them, some don't - it did not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either make it non-async or return a promise back to the caller (you can return that promise directly to the runtime). Like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'ca-central-1'});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});

    const params = {
        TableName: 'trivia-users',
        Key: {
            name: {
                S: 'Bobas'
            }
        }
    }

    return ddb.getItem(params, null).promise();

};
```

Comment: Thank you Jorge!